# WinPython: Spyder keeps breaking down

Tags: python, editor, spyder

So I have just downloaded and installed WinPython. I have included the directory to my Path (it probably sounds very dumb, but I don't even know what this means. I was just told this is important and so I have followed a tutorial).

Now, when I open the Spyder editor the editor never stops loading. It opens, but I can't do anything with it, because it just won't react. I have no clue whatsoever what I did wrong!

Comment: Please use Anaconda instead of WinPython. Anaconda is better maintained and has more support.

Comment: ok. I have installed Anaconda. And I have created a "Spyder" Icon on my Desktop, everything runs fine. The Jupyter Notebook is saved in this directory: C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Anaconda3 (64-bit)

Comment: There is an icon on which I can click and then the Jupyter Notebook opens. But it doesn't open using the command window like this: `cd C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Anaconda3 (64-bit) Jupyter Notebook`

Comment: do you know why?